# script malfunctioning when added to character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple code that kicks the ball in the direction the player is facing, it worked fine when I tested it with a cube as player but,
now when I added the same script to player character it's only kicking the ball when it's all x, y, z rotation is zero
the code:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) 
{
    Vector3 kickDirection=playerfrount.position - playerback.position;
                
    kickDirection = kickDirection.normalized;
    Debug.Log(kickDirection);
    //Vector3 forwardd = transform.forward;
    carryingBallplayer = false;
    rbb.AddForce(kickDirection  * kickForceplayer, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

I am expecting that the player character kicks in the direction it's facing

Comment: What is `playerfrount` and `playerback`? Are you sure the `kickDirection` is correct? what spoke against using the `player.transform.forward` direction?

Comment: playerfrount and playerback are two planes plased frount and back of player,and i think they are kickDirection is correct

Comment: hard to say without further information.. the code looks fine to me .. except we don't know of course if the force you use is actually enough.. you might want to rather directly change its velocity.. otherwise imagine player A kicked the ball into one direction and player B applies the same force in contrary direction => result the ball stops instead of expected flying in the contrary direction..